# Azure SQL Database throws Null insertion exception

Tags: c#, azure, entity-framework-core, azure-sql-database, asp.net-core-3.1

Programmatically seeding the database with the Azure App Service console throws the following error message:

`SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Id'`

However, programmatically seeding the database locally is error free. What could be the issue?

**Failed Solutions:**

- Set the `Id` column as `Nullable` directly in database
- Annotate the entity class with
  the`[Keyless]` attribute
- Annotate the entity class's `Id` property    with the `[Key]`
  attribute

**Table Schema**

```
+-------------+---------------+-------------+
| Table Name: Cities                        |
+-------------+---------------+-------------+
| Column Name |   Data Type   | Allow Nulls | 
+-------------+---------------+-------------+
| Id (PK)     | int           |     NO      |
| CityCode    | int           |     NO      |
| Name        | nvarchar(MAX) |     YES     |
| State       | nvarchar(MAX) |     YES     |
| Country     | nvarchar(MAX) |     YES     | 
+-------------+---------------+-------------+
```

**Entity Class:**

```
public class City
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public int CityCode { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string State { get; set; }
  public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

**Seeding Code:**

```
public class DbInitializer : IDbInitializer
{
    private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _scopeFactory;
    private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _hostEnvironment;

    public DbInitializer(IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory, IWebHostEnvironment environment)
    {
        _scopeFactory = scopeFactory;
        _hostEnvironment = environment;
    }

    public void Initialize()
    {
        using (var serviceScope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope())
        {
            using (var context = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<ApplicationDbContext>())
            {
                context.Database.EnsureCreatedAsync();
            }
        }
    }

    public async Task SeedData()
    {
        using (var serviceScope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope())
        {
            using (var context = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<ApplicationDbContext>())
            {
                if (!context.Cities.Any())
                {
                    string path = Path.Combine(_hostEnvironment.WebRootPath, "citylist.json");
                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path))
                    {
                        string jsonData = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        List<City> cityList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<City>>(jsonData);
                        await context.Cities.AddRangeAsync(cityList);
                        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How can a primary key be nullable? Even your database schema shows it doesn't allow `null`s. Could you please provide the seeding code?

Comment: `KeyLess` entities must be used for read only purposes (e.g read from view or custom sql query), and by definition it's key less, it doesn't have key.

Comment: I added the seeding code to the question. And I'm using the table for read only purposes, but using the `[Keyless]` attribute throws an exception stating that an entity must have a primary key.

Comment: Are there records in `city list.json` without `Id`? And is the same `city list.json` used for both ways (azure vs local) of seeding?

Comment: Have I got that right that `City` entity is not a `Keyless` one?

Comment: The `json` object for each city in the `citylist.json` file does not have an `id` property. So, I suppose the entity can be `[Keyless]` but it is throwing an exception stating that an entity must have a primary key. And yes, the `json` file is used both ways.

Comment: The table schema shows that your table have primary key called `Id` of type integer. This in turn means that this column can't have `null` as its value. So the value for this column is either generated by a database if it's an identity column or should be provided by the inserting code. So if your seed file doesn't have ids for cities, then I believe you want to make the column to be an identity column, so that the database generates id

Comment: It's not allowed to use `Keyless` entities for write purposes (your seeding logic does this)

Comment: It should be set as identity in your case, because you don't provide ids. And I would recommend to get rid of `Keyless` attribute for the `City` entity.

Comment: It's working after I set the column as an identity column. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source of the problem was that the `Id` column was not set as the identity column, thus disabling auto increments on the column. And since I'm not providing an `id` value, the database attempted a Null insertion and threw the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if the source data is having a value as NULL instead of an actual NULL

Similar kind of case happened with me where the data was having NULL as string value and not the usual NULL, integer columns won't allow such strings

Just to rule out this possibility, this check can be done if you can extract the source data in an excel and check for any such string value

Comment: Good to hear that it worked